# Rserve / R stacks on parallel processing

Tags: java, r, parallel-processing, rserve

I am building a Java REST application that calls R function through Rserve, which I am running on Ubuntu. The R function, that I am calling make a call to the Oracle via RJDBC database, collects data and so on.

From the documentation I understood, that if I am running Rserve on linux systems I don't need to start the separate instances on different ports and it is enough to have one running Rserve instance.

So I am creating a connection like this:

```
public static synchronized RConnection getConnection() throws RserveException {
if(connection == null || !connection.isConnected()) {
    connection = new RConnection(HOST);
    init(connection);
}
return connection;
```

}

Everything works fine for 1 user but in parallel, I am getting the error:

```
Error in .jcall("java/sql/DriverManager", "Ljava/sql/Connection;", "getConnection",  : 
  ignoring SIGPIPE signal
```

Should I create a separate connection for each call or I should make calls within one connection?

Answer (score 0):

You should make new rjdbc connection (and I think initialize rjava) for each request since requests are handled in forks. And db connections are now fork safe.